# How to use RealVNC, TightVNC server via repeater?

Tags: vnc, vnc-server, tightvnc

I have found UltraVNC server support repeater by using ID:xxx to sending to repeater. But in realvnc, tightvnc dont have.
So how to get this function or need to build custom from their open source ?

Answer (score 3):

TightVNC has a repeater program that can act as a gateway to other VNC machines. They refer to it as vnc reflector at http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-reflector/  you will still need to open a port on your firewall to the machine that has the reflector (aka repeater) installed on it.